# Link ToC page numbers instead of the sections

Tags: table-of-contents

[image: Link the page numbers instead of the other parts]
I need to be able to click on the table of contents page numbers and only them. I do not wish for the text to be clickable.

Comment: Use option `linktocpage` in your call to `hyperref`.